# Why is tx.gasprice always zero?

Tags: solidity

I have this modifier, and it never allows the method to be called as "tx.gasprice" always seems to be zero. Does anyone know why that is?

```
modifier gasPriceIsValid() {
        require(tx.gasprice != 0);
        _;
    }
```

Comment: Try to add an error message to require. With this, you can understand is the revert comes from this modifier.

Comment: I already did, and the revert comes from this modifier

Comment: Which network do you use?

Comment: Our own network which is currently just a test network

Comment: Do you specify the gas prices on your client-side?

Comment: I have MetaMask determine the gas price. It says 1,1

Comment: Could you try to send a tx from a script?